# Android sub activity

Tags: android

Iám new in android.

My questions about sub-activity.

Main activity with child sub-activity 1 and 2.

I have a Main activity with 3 buttons with these buttuns i pass values to my child activity number 2 and in child 2 i do something with these values.

When i push the button in child 2 i would return the values to child number 1 and put the values in TextViews.

Now my problem is when i finish child 2 the values return automaticaly to the Main activity.

This not what i want is there solution for this.

Were can i place startActivityForResult . I don't want to place it in the Main activity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the values as extras to the Intent that you use to start child 1, just as you did when you passed values to child 2.